# Defining a split function ourselves in python

Tags: python-3.x

my friend tells me that he is often asked in his college to create programs without using inbuilt python functions. he asked me to write the code for inbuilt split function. This is what i wrote

```
a="I love to play chess"
y=[]
str1=""
c=list(a)
print(c)
for char in c:
    if char==" ":
        y.append(str1)
        str1=""
    else:
        str1=str1+char
print(y)
```

But i get only the first four words? Please help me in identifying what is going wrong here?
The output is-['I', 'love', 'to', 'play']

Comment: `list.append()` is also built-in function, why did you use it?

Comment: my friend was okay with append being used

Comment: Think about when you add completed words to the output list.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest There is a difference between `built-in` function and `built-in's` function. `split` is an utility `built-in` while `append` is an essential function to work with `built-in` `list`. Try to understand the difference.

Comment: just for increasing my knowledge, is there any  substitute available for append?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the append of the last word. Notice the line above the `print(y)` which appends the last `str1` after the loop ends:

```
a="I love to play chess"
y=[]
str1=""
c=list(a)
print(c)
for char in c:
    if char==" ":
        y.append(str1)
        str1=""
    else:
        str1=str1+char
y.append(str1)
print(y)
```

Comment: In the second last line , you have to append the last string formed.